# Braintree - require CVV for saved payment method

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree

I am integrating Braintree's dropin JS widget into our project.
On server side, I generate client token with customerId, which causes that dropin is showing customer's saved payment methods (credit cards).

However, due to our security policy we should require a CVV each time user wants to make a transaction (even for previously saved credit cards).

[image]

I've tried to override some CVV fields, but it doesn't effect saved credit cards.

```
braintree.dropin.create({
    authorization: token,
    container: "#braintree-form",
    card: {
        overrides: {
            cvv: true //doesn't change anything
        }
    }
}, //(...) rest of code)
```

Is there any way to use dropin and force CVV typing each time user wants to use saved payment method?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot accomplish this above. I'd recommend using Hosted Fields if this is what you want to do, since the Drop-in does not support removing/editing saved payment methods at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable cvv rules from your Control Panel

1. Log into the Control Panel
2. Navigate to Settings > Processing > Fraud Tools
3. Under AVS or CVV, click Options
4. Select your desired AVS or CVV rejection criteria
   You have the option to apply the rules to all transactions or only to specific card types, amounts, or merchant accounts
5. Click Save

More information [here](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/fraud-tools/basic/avs-cvv-rules)

Comment: I've them enabled, it doesn't affect anything.